# If $f:(-1,1) \rightarrow (-1,1)$ is a bijection and satisfies $|f(x) - f(y)| = |x-y|$ , $\forall x,y \in (-1,1)$ then $f(0) = 0$ .

Tags: real-analysis

I know that if $g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection and satisfies $|g(x) - g(y)| = |x-y|$ then $g(x) = a\cdot x + b$ with $|a| = 1$.

So, I tried to prove that $f$ has the form $f(x) = a\cdot x$ with $|a| = 1$
but I couldn’t prove this.

Is there an easier to attack this problem?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First set $x=1$ and $y=-1$ to deduce $f(-1)$ is either $+1$ or $-1$. If it's -1 then check $f(y)=y$ for all $y$ with $x=1$ and varying $y$. If it's 1 then etc etc. Doesn't this work?

Comment: The interval is open not closed, so we cannot take $x = 1$ or $y = -1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f$ is bijective there is some $a \in (-1,1)$ such that $f(a) = 0$. Using the given identity note that for all $x \in (-1,1)$, $|f(x)| = |f(x) - f(a)| = |x - a|$. But since $f$ has image $(-1,1)$, $|f(x)| < 1$ which allows us to easily pick a value of $x$ to get a contradiction if $a \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Your identity implies that $f$ is continuous on the interval $(-1,1)$.

Continuous bijections on intervals are strictly monotone (easy to show by intermediate value theorem). We can safely assume that $f$ is strictly increasing.

After that, we can remove the absolute value: for $x>y$ we have $f(x)-f(y)=x-y$, therefore $f(x)-x=f(y)-y$ whenever $x>y$. It easy to see that the left hand side depends only on $x$  and the right hand side only on $y$, hence $\exists c\in \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)=x+c$. Now take into account that $f:(-1,1)\to (-1,1)$, this gives you $c=0$ and thus $f(0)=0$.

The proof for the case of decreasing $f$ is absolutely the same.